# Best way to show DB error message when a "Delete" hits a DB constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am learning MVC3 and EF4.1 . I am currently experimenting with Database first EF with the new the TT4 generator to generate lean data classes. I have generated a CRUD controller, and have come across the issue of how best to display DB constraint messages in the View.

My code is so far:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, aspnet_Users User)
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here
            db.Entry(User).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            return Content(err.InnerException.StackTrace);
            //return View();
        }
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the simplest things to do is add a model error with the exception message. This essentially treats the constraint violation as a validation error. You should probably customize the message for the user, however.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Guid id, aspnet_Users User)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add delete logic here
        db.Entry(User).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, err.Message);
        return View(User);
    }
}
```

Comment: First a big thank you for a very quick response. I have added some code to the view: "<div>    @Html.ValidationSummary(true) </div>" which produces "•An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details." However I need more than this. Thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: That's where the custom message comes into play. You'll have to inspect the exception and update the message accordingly.

Comment: Ok, just worked this one out. I have added:             catch (Exception err)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, err.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                return View(User);
            }

Comment: I am sure that I am feeding back on this incorrectly. Should I be putting my new code in my original answer block? Also What is best practice for managing these DB errors and feeding back to the user. A big thank you again for your help. Ed

Comment: Just discovered ELMAH. This sounds neat.

Comment: Your comments here are fine. Typically you'll want to use an error logging utility such as Elmah to log any unhandled exceptions. If the error is caused by something the user can fix by changing their input, you're better off telling them how to fix it in a helpful validation message.